# Multi-Thead Multi-Server Architecture

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, sockets

Im at the planning stage of a project where I have to make something like a special type of conference system, where pairs of remote computers can connect and exchange data via different servers.

So computer 1B and computer 1A can communicate with each other by connecting to any of the servers. For example computer 1A can connect to server 1, and computer 1B can connect to server 2, then both servers will somehow find each other and connect to each other so that computer 1A and 1B can communicate through the servers.

There is a common database that all servers have access to that has information on which computers are allowed to communicate with each other.

SERVER 1: COMPUTER 1A <----socket----> thread 1A <--->database

SERVER 2: COMPUTER 1B <----socket----> thread 1B <--->database

Each server listens for incoming connection, spawning a thread to handle each connection.

When a thread is created, it must locate the server and thread for the corresponding computer and connect to that other servers thread, so that the computers can communicate via the 2 servers/threads.

Computers 1A and 1B can connect/disconnect at random times, maybe one or both computers are not connected, but if both are connected they should be able to communicate via the 2 servers/threads.

For example, if computer 1A want to send data to computer 1B, it sends the data over the socket to thread 1A, thread 1A is to somehow find thread 1B on a different server and connect to that thread, so that the computers 1A and 1B can communicate via the threads.

Im having problems figuring out how a thread on one server can locate and communicate with a specific thread on another server.

There can be thousands of pairs of computers constantly connecting and disconnecting from any of the servers, and each server must be able to find the server/thread of its corresponding computer and connect to it.

Since there is a common database, maybe some information like the server/IP/port of both threads can be stored there when a computer connects to any server. But since all threads on a particular server have the same ip/port number, i dont see how that could be used to differentiate the threads.

Polling is not allowed.

I havnt chosen a programming language to write the server in, but in thinking PYTHON on apache. Anybody have an idea how to architect this?

Thanks

Comment: *thread 1A is to somehow find thread 1B on a different server and connect to that thread* - Bad Logic, bad bad architecture. You should utilise your database here to store data for your users. And, depending on the availability of the client, push the message intended for 1B from the server.

Comment: AM_I_HELPFUL, thanks for your comment, there are 2 servers, one connected to computer 1A, the other to computer 1B, when 1A writes user data to the database, how will the thread on computer 1B know that data was written to data base intended for it so that it can get and push that data to the user?

Comment: It will create an open connection with the server, and as soon as the data is written to the database. Nowadays, protocols like WebSocket exist which support this concept. Hope this helps @Programmer2